# What does this mean $();?

Tags: jquery

```
$();
```

I think it's from jQuery.  I'm used to using `$(document).ready(function(){});` from jQuery but someone used `$(function(){});` and I'm confused how you could have an anonymous function within the `$();`.

Answer (score 6):

`jQuery(function () { })`, or `$(function () { })`, is shorthand for `jQuery(document).ready(function () { })`. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh I'm used to the long version, guess I'll be using this shorthand from now.  thanks!

Comment: @Kim I always go with `jQuery(function ($) { })`. It's short, precise and compatible in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3), wrapping a callback in `$()` executes the callback when the page is ready (similar to using `$(document).ready(callback)`, or (I believe) immediately if the document is already ready.